# how to get unique records using pentaho data integration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-design-studio

I have log_table with columns state,region,district,timestamp in sql

server.

```
ID     state     region     district     timestamp
--     -----     ------     --------     ---------
1       GJ        RE056       DI137      2014-02-05 09:00:00.257
2       CA        RE027       DI154      2014-02-04 14:00:00.183 
3       GJ        RE056       DI137      2014-12-09 16:00:00.257
```

I would like to load these records to another table in mysql with unique records and the existing data should not insert into new table in mysql while loading the data from sql server to mysql, only daily updated 
records should load in to the new table with out duplicate records. Help me in this issue how to do using pentaho data integration.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Try putting some sample data to demonstrate what you want to achieve or something which you have tried.

Comment: Dont you have a datetime column? How can we identify a record is daily updated? Please elaborate more on this. I can help you

Comment: @ Marlon Abeykoon thanks for u r reply above i mentioned column timestamp it's data type is datetime

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `timestamp` column stands for `last_updated_timestamp` of a row from source database (sql server).

If your goal is to run the transformation daily and you expect that only `new or updated` records from source database will be loaded to target (mysql) database, you need to store the `timestamp` into target database (e.g. table `log_target`) and the transformation steps could be:

- **Table input (target db):** Get MAX `timestamp` from table `log_target`.

  - `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), '1970-01-01 00:00:00') AS max FROM log_target`
- **Table input (source db):** Select updated data from `log_table`

  - **Step settings:** Insert data step (to obtain data from previous step); Replace variables in script? (true)
  - `SELECT * FROM log_table WHERE (timestamp > ?)`
- Process your data
- **Table output or Insert/Update (target db):** Store output data to `log_target` table. Don't forget to store `timestamp` value.

Comment: @ mzy thanks for reply i have not understood the line To store the timestamp into target database. it means i need to keep timestamp column as  TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: No, the `timestamp` value (target db) needs to correspond to `timestamp` value from source db. E.g. yesterday you loaded those three records from your example to the target db (`ID, state, region, district, timestamp`). The max `timestamp` is "2014-12-09 16:00:00.257" now in target db. Right now your transformation / job is executed. You obtain MAX `timestamp` from target db and see it is "2014-12-09 16:00:00.257". From source database you load all rows which have `timestamp value > target.max` ("2014-12-09 16:00:00.257") and store them into target db.

Comment: @ hi mzy thanks for help it's working in between yesterday i have loaded data from source to target up to [2,113,723] rows of [2014-04-06 16:45:00  TO  2015-01-19 07:41:43]  middle with server issue connection stopped loading data. when again i tried to load it is giving me error like duplicate entry '2327745' for key 'PRIMARY'.Here if i want  to start loading data from 2015-01-19 07:41:45 to current date. what is process i have to follow

Comment: [Accept my answer if it helps.] The problem is that some row already exists in the target db and you try to load it once more which throws this error. I don't know which step do you use for loading the data to target db, but I recommend to use the Insert/Update step (inserts row when missing, updates row when present) with this settings: Key to look up = lookup primary key of target table; Update fields: Update = Y for all fields except your primary key (Update = N); Don't perform any updates = false.

Comment: @ thanks for u r reply. Here i am using Table Output step to load data to target db

Comment: Try to use `Insert/Update` step instead of `Table Output`. Steps are very similar but `Table Output` can be used only for inserting data. If you use `Insert/Update` in dual mode it will insert data and if some data is present in db it will be updated and won't cause any error.
Anyway, could you accept my original answer? :)

Comment: It's working and i have used select values with  insert/update step but in between it missing few rows

Comment: By `accepting` I mean `stackoverflow accept` = Click on a tick (Accept button) next to the header of my answer. This makes the tick green and adds me few `stackoverflow points` for `correct answer`.

Comment: If i schedule a job for above task.When it loading data from sql server to mysql with the records of 50,000 to 1,00,000, if job fails after loading data up to 50,000 records with any error like GC over head limit exceeded (or) any other error. How to update another 50,000 records With out doing manually to update timestamp.What is the procedure i need to follow

Answer (score 0):

Table Input -> sort rows (state,region,district,timestamp descending) -> Unique rows       ->Insert / Update.

Sort rows timestamp descending will help you keep last modified record after remove duplicate.